# How to implement dynamic tab completion of options in Fish shell?

Tags: fish

I want to implement dynamic tab completion of options to a Fish command. This is easy for the `-a` switch, but I can't figure out how to do it for the `-l` switch.

Consider the following lines:

```
$ complete -c foo -a '(echo bar\nbaz\nbiz)' -f
$ complete -c foo -l '(echo bar\nbaz\nbiz)' -f
```

The behavior of my shell is then as follows:

```
$ foo b<tab>
  bar  baz  biz

$ foo --<tab>
  foo --\(echo\ bar\\nbaz\\nbiz\)
```

Instead I'd like it to suggest three options `--bar`, `--baz` and `--biz`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit: Now I understand better. You can do this by just making your "arguments" start with dashes. Here's an example that uses a function for clarity:

```
function get_foo_completions
  echo --bar
  echo --baz
  echo --biz

  set prev_arg (commandline -pco)[-1]
  test "$prev_arg" = print
  and echo --conditional
end

complete -c foo -a '(get_foo_completions)' -f
```

The `--conditional` argument will only be printed if the previous argument is `print` which illustrates that these can be dynamic.

<s>To my knowledge this isn't yet possible. Options are declarative, and only arguments to those options may be dynamic.</s>

If you give more details about your use case I might be able to suggest other approaches.

Comment: I'm writing completions for a command with a large set of subcommands that change pretty often (some are added, some are removed). Those subcommands in turn have options that are unique to each subcommand. I'm parsing the help output of the root command to obtain a list of subcommands, and then I parse the help output of each subcommand to obtain the available options to each subcommand. If I do this beforehand (in the completion file itself) I get severe lag (multiple seconds), which is not acceptable. I therefore want to provide the help-parsing function to `complete`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Just for clarity's sake: I'm writing completions for `lncli`, the CLI interface to [`lnd`](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd)

Comment: This is still not an ideal solution, though. This causes the options to be suggested regardless of if the user has written `-` or not. In a perfect world I'd preferred those to only appear if the user writes `-`

Comment: See the `prev_arg` example - you can do arbitrary parsing of the command line and dynamically offer whatever completions you like.  This is how e.g. the git completions work.

You might be interested in `__fish_complete_subcommand` for subcommand support.